# Controller resource passed to factory is undefined (AngularJs)

Tags: angularjs

I'm having a problem passing param from controller to my factory.
This is my controller and this is the way i was working for whole application, but suddenly this controller has a problem.

```
controllers.userCtrl = function($scope, $routeParams, userFactory, productsFactory){
    var user = $routeParams.param1;
    userFactory.getUserByUserName(user).then(function(data){
        $scope.user = data[0];
        $scope.userName = data[0].user_name;
        console.log($scope.userName);  //line 428
    })
    productsFactory.getOtherUserProducts(1).then(function(data){
        console.log($scope.userName); //line 431
        $scope.products = data;
    })
}
```

My factory

```
factory.getOtherUserProducts = function(userNameData){
    console.log(userNameData); //line 102
    return $http.get($location.protocol() + '://' + $location.host() + '/server/api/products/getOtherUserProducts/'+userNameData);
}
```

And the console out put is:

```
factory.js:102     undefined
controllers.js:428 treutel.lesley
controllers.js:431 treutel.lesley
```

Why argument isn't passed to factory. This is the way i was building application whole time..

If you need any additional informations, please let me know and i will provide.

Comment: Maybe the log you're seeing is from some other call to `getOtherUserProducts` ..? Can you creae a [mcve]..?

Comment: i will, but a little bit later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

changing controller a little bit did the trick

```
controllers.userCtrl = function($scope, $routeParams, userFactory, productsFactory){
    var user = $routeParams.param1;
    userFactory.getUserByUserName(user).then(function(data){
        $scope.user = data[0];
        productsFactory.getOtherUserProducts(data[0].user_name).then(function(data){
            $scope.products = data;
        })
    })
}
```